# Import products from MySQL data base in Odoo data base

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I try to connect odoo to mysql database to import product list from mysql in odoo data base. What is the best way to do that ?

thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  One of the things that would make your [question better](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is to show the sort of approaches have you tried already, and how they have not met your needs.  The community can then suggest solutions for specific issues that you have encountered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the MySQL part you should definitely go with [PyMySQL](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL). It works like a bliss and is very well documented.
Regarding Odoo you might want to take a look at [OdooRPC](http://pythonhosted.org/OdooRPC/), it seems like a very straightforward way to pilot the servers using Python.

Comment: @Samik If my answer solved your problem please mark it as the accepted answer. You're very welcome.